# apache2 .htaccess error on ubuntu + apache2 + rvm + passenger + rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, .htaccess, apache2, passenger

I followed https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/index.html
to setup my ubuntu server

Installed

- apache2, mysql, imagemagick, ... as "root" instead of "sudo"
- "rvm" as user. passenger as user

When I access my rails site, I get this error as in /var/log/apache2/error.log

`(13)Permission denied: /home/my_home_directory/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable`

1. What am I missing here?
2. Did I do something very wrong by installing
   basic packages as "root" instead of "sudo"? (How to fix that, if at all)

Comment: Silly error. :) My home folder for the user did not have world readable permission. changed /home/user_directory to 755 and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to change rights on this file, to give read access to your webserver user.

```
chmod o+r /home/my_home_directory/.htaccess
```

Also, this question probably belongs to Serverfault.

Comment: There is no .htacess file there. I have another VPS working on similar installation and that too does not require an any .htaccess

Comment: In this case, it would be a good idea to look at your Apache/Rails config because it is clearly looking for a .htaccess file in this directory.

Comment: Thanks Pierre. The problem was very silly and obvious. I just had to focus on it after a pause. Fixed now. Please check my comment above.

Comment: No problem ! Just be aware that 755 means read and execute access for everyone and also write access for the owner of the file. If you are hosted on a shared server, this might be an issue.

Comment: Private VPS. :) I am not much of a shared server user. Did all setup myself from ubuntu installation to everything else.